# Limit AWS Lambda to poll dynamo db streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I currently have a dynamo db table which adds new records at 80 TPS. Now, I want to do some processing on these records and I'm planning to trigger a Lambda function from a dynamo db stream on the addition of a new record. This Lambda will take the record and do some sort of processing which might take 15 seconds. So, that means my Lambda might invoke around 1200 (80*15) functions at a time which is way beyond the limits. So, I wanted to understand if anyone has tried a mechanism to limit the way a Lambda polls the dynamo db stream?

I tried going through the documentation but couldn't find any meaningful information to see if we can limit the Lambda to poll the dynamo db streams

Comment: You can easily increase the default lambda limits.

Answer (score 0):

If the main thing you're trying to do here is to limit the number of concurrent executions of a single Lambda function, then it's possible by setting concurrency limits on that function, please see the AWS docs for more details: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/